# Get a list of functions for a DLL

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building a project. It's an application that users can add their extensions (DLL files) to. To manage an extension, I need to get its list of classes, functions, etc. Is there code for doing it?

Note: I am using C#.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a particular assembly, you can use [`Assembly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) to get the types, then for each type call [`Type.GetMethods()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx), [`Type.GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx) etc, or just [`Type.GetMembers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmembers.aspx).

However, for plugin functionality it's usually a good idea to have a common interface which the plugins have to implement - that reduces the amount of reflection you need to use. Use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) to check whether a type is compatible with a particular interface.

You might also want to look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mef) which can make implementing an extension system easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about building an extensible application in C# that loads other assemblies and uses their contents for extending the application, then see Stack Overflow question *[System with plugins in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515925/system-with-plugins-in-c/515972#515972)*.